# Regex number validation issue

Tags: regex

I want to validate the regex with below test cases. I tried the below regex but it only passes one.

```
1 - fail
  0.1 - success
 .10 - fail
 .03 - fail
 .0001 - fail (max 4 digits after decimal point)
 .1 - fail



 ^(?![0.]*$)\d+(\d{3})*\.?\d{1,6}$
```

Comment: What are the rules for the type of number which is valid?

Comment: the failed I mentioned should work and all the non decimal nos.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question actually.

Comment: ok, both decimal and non decimal nos should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match only if starting with a digit (excluding negative numbers), optionally followed by a dot and 0-4 digits.

Regex: `^[0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?$`.

Also, [0-9] can be replaced by `\d`.

Regex: `^\d*(?:\.\d{0,4})?$`.

**Special Case/ Corner case to exclude `0.0` (as per OP's request):**

Regex:`^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d*(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?)$`

**PS:** As you have not mentioned any specific rules, I assumed any number and decimal number with 4 digits after the decimal point.

Also, this regex passes all the test cases mentioned.

Thanks to **@TreffnonX** for the suggestion.

I have tested the final expression on https://regexr.com with additional test cases:

[image]

Comment: Can be written with `\d` instead of the `[0-9]`: `^\d*(?:\.\d{0,4})?$`

Comment: it is accepting 0.0

Comment: Check now @boycod3

Comment: can we include  comma, for example 1,000 and so on?

Comment: Sure. I would suggest you to raise a new question with all the rules properly defined. Your scenario looks interesting.

Comment: @Deepak Tatyaji Ahire
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64385300/regex-number-amount-validation