# Regex number amount validation

Tags: regex

I want to validate the amount with the below scenario. The below regex is working except ',' for example 1,000.0000

```
^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d*(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?)$

1 - should pass
0.1 - should pass
.1 - should pass
0 - should fail
.0001 - should pass
.10 - should pass
0.0  - should fail
0.00000 - should fail (only accept 4 digits after the decimal point)
1.0000 - should pass
1,000.0000 - should pass
1,000,00.000 - should pass
1,000.0000 - should pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(?![0,]*(\.0+)?$)([,\d]*(?:\.[0-9]{0,4})?)$`. I simply replaced the `\d` before the decimal separator with `[,\d]`; and also in the negative assertion, so that `0,000.00` doesn't match. It allows any number of commas placed everywhere, and this is reasonable, because local traditions of grouping digits differ.

Also, do you want numbers with hanging dots, like `10.` to match? If not, replace `{0,4}` with `{1,4}`.
https://regex101.com/r/XB8OtL/3.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the last `?` (zero or one repetition) with a `*` (any number of repetitions) (so `^(?!0*(.0+)?$)(\d*(?:.[0-9]{0,4})*)$`) will validate the inputs that should validate (it's the repetition of the `,000` or `.000` that fails the test). By the way your regex could be improved: because you use `.` (any character) instead of `\.` (dot) or ',' coma, your regex ie validate bad inputs like '1x0000' or '1#0000' (any character)